# Making vertical nested scroll always visible

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I have the following Xaml. I have a grid containing some "columnheaders" and a list box. Currently my horizontal scroll bar scroll both the column headers and the listbox. My vertical scroll bar only scrolls the listbox as I want the column header "frozen". The issue I have is that I have to scroll all the way to the right to see the vertical scroll bar. Is there anyway of "locking" the vertical scroll bar to be always visible ( when its required ) and for it to only scroll the listbox? Please let me know if you need anymore information.

```
<Grid Name="test1" Margin="0,0,50,0" Grid.Row="0">
    <ScrollViewer  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="{Binding ElementName=test1, Path=ActualWidth}">
        <Grid Name="grdMain"  >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                    <ItemsControl  Name="ColumnHeaders" ..>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Name="check" Grid.Row="1">
                    <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding ElementName=check, Path=ActualHeight}"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                        <ListBox   Name="lstDrop" ..>
                        </ListBox>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
         </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
```

Here are screen shots of current functionality:

[image: Scrolling without bar visible]

[image: Scrolling with bar visible]

Comment: What about a manuall scrollbar in a new column bound to the horizontal scrollbar of the listbox?

Comment: Would you be able to post a code example as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, it was a bit nastier as I thought. Nevertheless, here is some stuff. I had to do some changes on the initial idea and your layout, but afterwards it'll look all the same.

```
<Grid Name="test1" Margin="0,0,50,0" Grid.Row="0">
    <Grid Name="grdMain"  >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="90*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Name="scv_headers">
            <ItemsControl Name="ColumnHeaders">
                <!--Headers here-->
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollChanged="List_OnScrollChanged">
            <ListBox Name="lstDrop">
                <!--Items here-->
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Because the scrollbars are hidden in the template, I had to add some code behind

```
    private void List_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollbarSrc = (ScrollBar)((ScrollViewer)e.OriginalSource).Template.FindName("PART_HorizontalScrollBar", (ScrollViewer)e.OriginalSource);

        scv_headers.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(scrollbarSrc.Value);
    }
```

Because your stackpanels only contain one item, I left them away which looks pretty much the same.